# mapping a java pojo to an angular pojo

Tags: java, angular, spring-data-rest

I am retrieving an account object from the database so that I may compare its fields with the username and password fields that are submitted in the login screen.

I use the following code to retrieve it from the database and send it to the angular component.

```
  postCredentials(username:string, password:string): Promise<Account> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("username", username);
    params.append("password", password);
    console.log(this.data);
    return this.http.get(this.apiPostUrl, {params: params}).toPromise().then(res => res.json() as Account).catch(this.handleError);//this.http.get(this.apiPostUrl, {params: params}).toPromise().then(res => res.json() as Account)
  }
```

However, when I print the result I see that the id field in the Account angular pojo is undefined, as is the Roles field. Now I can understand that the roles field is undefined, but the id field should not be undefined because it has a value in the database.

These are my pojo's.

The java account Pojo:

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Role> roles;
    @OneToOne
    private Person person;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", username='" + username + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", roles=" + roles +
            ", person=" + person +
            '}';
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

and this is the frontend (angular) pojo

```
export class Account {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  person: Person;
  roles: Role[];
}
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm missing here?

Comment: check in the console if the result from your http request matches what you expect

Comment: I found out that the Spring data REST repositories return a HAL document instead of a regular json object. Time to switch to Spring Data and use regular Restcontrollers instead..

Comment: SDR only exposes entity IDs if you configure it do so.